# REXEX match a String and select up to a char

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regular expression where I can match the initial of the string and then replace anything after an specific char.... like for example:

String = 123456789:0:0  => Output = 123456789:2:4

I need a regex where it need to match "123" in the begging then replace only "0:0" by another String.

to match "123" is easy:  ^123, but I cannot find a way after this to go up to : and replace only the rest of string.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a negated character class to match up till the first occurrence of a colon.

In the replacement use capture group 1, followed by the replacement.

```
^(123[^:]*:)0:0$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(123[^:]*:)` Match `123` followed by 0+ times any char except `:` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
- `0:0` Match literally
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9IMgM1/1)

If you want to replace all after matching the first colon, you could use `.+`

```
^(123[^:]*:).+
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XWeLW6/1)

Comment: Thanks! I tested this and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your exact programming context it seems like you're using a version of a regex_replace function.  With suitable grouping this is easy to do.

Don't think of what you want to replace.  Think about what you want to keep.

```
^(.*?123.*?:)(0:0)(.*?)$
```

And as your replacement string use

```
$12:4$3
```

Comment: Hi Cris. I tested it and it works.... can you comment for what I need (.*?) at the end? Thanks

Comment: You don't actually need it, but you would also have to remove the $ at the end as well, and take out the $3 from your replacement.  Regex replace retains whatever does not match.  I was trying to show that you need capturing group parens around the beginning of the string and the end of the string in order to retain them in what gets replaced.  The $1 in the replacement string substitutes back whatever matched the first parenthesis set.

Answer (score 0):

For replacing the "0:0", you can use:

```
Numbers between 123 and 0:0 => /^(123[0-9]+:)0:0/ replace ${1}2:4
```

OR

```
Anything between 123 and 0:0 => /^(123.+:)0:0/ replace ${1}2:4
```

This RegExp creates a group starting with 123 until it reaches 0:0 and later we use the group in the replacement string. This however depends on the programming language you use:

**Example in PHP**

```php
$result = preg_replace("/^(123[0-9]+:)0:0/", "\${1}2:4", "123456789:0:0");
```

**Example in JavaScript**

```js
let result = "123456789:0:0".replace(/^(123[0-9]+:)0:0/, "$12:4");
```

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript:

```js
const str = `123456789:0:0`;
console.log(str.replace(/(?<=^123[^:]*:).*/, `2:4`));
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/OXSFSh/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    123                      '123'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^:]*                    any character except: ':' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```